# Model stops simulating when exporting data from database

Tags: anylogic

I am exporting data from my AnyLogic model by writing/apending each run a text file from data that is being saved to the internal database. I use the below code in the Experiment's `After simulation run` field:

```
// create header
file.println("id"+","+"replicate"+","+"diagnostic_pathway_duration"+","+"total_cost_patient"+","+
                "referred_gh"+","+"referred_th"+","+"tx_gh"+","+"tx_th"+","+"tx_ah"+","+"arrival_gh"+","+
                "complete_gh"+","+"arrival_th"+","+"complete_th"+","+"arrival_ah"+","+"complete_ah"+","+
                "pathway_concluded");

// Write data from dbase table                                
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(patient_export).list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
        file.println(        row.get( patient_export.id ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.replicate ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.diagnostic_pathway_duration ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.total_cost_patient ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.referred_gh ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.referred_th ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.tx_gh ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.tx_th ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.tx_ah ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.arrival_gh ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.complete_gh ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.arrival_th ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.complete_th ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.arrival_ah ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.complete_ah ) + "," + 
                                        row.get( patient_export.pathway_concluded ));
}
file.close();
deleteFrom(patient_export).execute();
```

In the `initial experiment setup` field I included this code:

```
deleteFrom(patient_export).execute();
```

However, after a while no more simulation runs are being executed. The model just does not progress any more, and the CPU is not being taxed. In one instance, the experiment stopped simulating after 45 iterations, which resulted in a text file of 210 mb with approximately 1.1million rows.

I am saving the data to the internal database by triggering a function in `Patient` using an event. This is the code:

```
insertInto(patient_export)
    .columns(patient_export.iteration, patient_export.replicate, patient_export.id, patient_export.diagnostic_pathway_duration,
             patient_export.total_cost_patient, patient_export.referred_gh, patient_export.referred_th, patient_export.tx_gh,
             patient_export.tx_th, patient_export.tx_ah, patient_export.arrival_gh, patient_export.complete_gh, patient_export.arrival_th,
             patient_export.complete_th, patient_export.arrival_ah, patient_export.complete_ah, patient_export.pathway_concluded
            ) //database tables
    .values(main.v_iteration, main.v_replicate, p_patientId, p_diagnostic_pathway_duration, p_totalCost, p_referred_GH, p_referred_TH,
            p_Tx_GH, p_Tx_TH, p_Tx_AH, p_timeArrivedDxGH, p_timeCompletedDxGH, p_timeArrivedDxTH, p_timeCompletedDxTH, p_timeArrivedDxAH,
            p_timeCompletedDxAH, p_diagnosticPathwayConcluded
    .execute();
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is the internal database playing up? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: does it work as expected when you turn off any dbase writing? Try first to find which part of the code is really causing the issue and report back ;) (i.e. the model writing or the after-experiment writing)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Benjamin. I've narrowed it down to how I'm saving data in the database. When I disable that function, I have no issues. Even though I use ```System.gc(); deleteFrom(patient_export).execute();```in my experiment, my database remains large (~500 mb), although no records are listed in my database tables. Ofcourse, model execution is not logged.

Comment: It seems that it is not specific to my model. When I run this model (https://sdaza.com/blog/2020/anylogic-database/) for instance, it stops simulating when the database reaches a size of ~300 mb. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: in the dbase properties, there is a tickbox "auto-compress on exit" (or similar). try that.

Comment: There is no such option in 8.3.3 (university version)

Comment: see answer below, shouldn't be excluded in the Uni edition

Comment: I have not managed to fix this issue. I'm using a workaround by running a SQL server and saving my data to it.

Answer (score 0):

Compact the base on close:

[image]

See help article under Properties: https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fconnectivity%2Fdatabase.html&resultof=%22%64%61%74%61%62%61%73%65%22%20%22%64%61%74%61%62%61%73%22%20

Comment: I saw that in the help documentation, but the option is not present in my AnyLogic version  (University 8.3.3). Thanks though.

Comment: you can execute a SQL statement manually that does this, the "COMPACT" statement does it...